# Regex to check if password contains at least one capital letter

Tags: jquery, regex

My regex is not very good, and I've been trying to figure this out by searching online. How would I check if an input value, such as a password, contains at least one capital letter?

So if my password was stored in a variable:

```
var pass = $("#inputPassword").val();
```

What would my regex be if I were to use:

```
regex.test(pass);
```

Note that is the only condition I am checking for, whether the password contains at least one capital letter, nothing else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd be simply checking if it contain any `[A-Z]` character range.

```
if (/[A-Z]+/.test($("#inputPassword").val())) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Password doesn't contain at least one capital letter
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`/[A-Z]+/` should solve most of your problems. Not sure about unicode support in js, though, but I think you would have to build a regex from ranges of unicode capital characters groups you would like to support (see this helpful table [reference](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lu/list.htm)). If you were to go that way, you might also take a look at this nifty tool called [regenerate](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/regenerate).

Answer (score 1):

Another regex to try:

```
var pass = $("#inputPassword").val();
var regex = new RegExp(/^(.*[A-Z].*)$/);
var valid = regex.test(pass)
```